# Should I use one or two queues?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I'm doing a microservice that produces messages for an ActiveMQ broker.

My posible messages are;
1) Logs for my application. 
2) The business messages I need.

Later I'll develop a microservice that consumes those messages, and I thought that it could be better to have two different queues at ActiveMQ.

My question is, should I use 2 queues, or should I use 1 queue with a flag to differenciate messages?

Comment: There's no one-size-fits-all here. Which solution you choose will depend on lots of different factors, and you've provided barely any info about your use-case, your constraints, your design goals, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we talk about microservices, it's about segregation of responsibilities and loosly coupled architecture which could be extensible lateron.

If you'll identify message based on flag

1. It will be harcoded even when messages are not related
2. Highly coupled architecture
3. Queue maintenance and scaling would be affected later on

and so on ..

I would recommend using different queues for `different types of messages` which serves `unique purpose`.